# Transaction don' work (Manager tx problem)

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions, spring-mybatis

Good day!
My problem is when i transferred configuration for another DB from xml to @Bean my transactions is lost.... dont rollback and not work.
I see this when in DB after first insert created row (!), but in this method(transaction) start second insert i take Exception and row after first inset stay on DB!

This xml

```
<bean name="sqlSessionFactoryYarus" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/MapperConfigYarus.xml" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceYarus" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="ru.project.crm.mapper_yarus"/>
    <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="sqlSessionFactoryYarus" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManagerYarus"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceYarus" />
    <qualifier value="yarus"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManagerYarus"  />
```

this code (dataSource there is no this not to waste space)

```
 @Component
 @Scope("singleton")
 @DependsOn("springApplicationContextHolder")
 public class YarusConnectionConfig {
@Bean
public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactoryYarus() throws Exception {
    SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
    sqlSessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSourceYarus());
    sqlSessionFactory.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("../MapperConfigYarus.xml"));
    return sqlSessionFactory.getObject();
}

@Bean
public MapperScannerConfigurer yarusMapper() throws Exception {
    MapperScannerConfigurer msc = new MapperScannerConfigurer();

    msc.setSqlSessionFactoryBeanName("sqlSessionFactoryYarus");
    msc.setBasePackage("ru.project.crm.mapper_yarus");
    return msc;
}
@Bean
public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManagerYarus() throws Exception {
    DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSourceYarus());
    return dataSourceTransactionManager;
}
}
```

And

All paces when i want to Transactional annotate @Transactional(value = "transactionManagerYarus")
And if i build project with xml Transactional works fine
BUT if build with @Bean its dont work...

Plesae Help me!

I use

1) Spring 4.3

2) MyBatis

3) Postgesql

4) Java 8

Comment: You need to add `@EnableTransactionManagement` to your configuration class as a replacement for `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManagerYarus"  />`. Also remove `@Scope` this isn't need and replace `@Component` with `@Configuration`.

Comment: ok, thx, try it

Comment: M. Deinum, I tried, but did not help. What else could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Also we find solution.
Problem was in dataSource

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "close", name = "dataSourceYarus")
public ComboPooledDataSource dataSourceYarus()  {
    ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    //config connection
}
```

It is my bean, and i call this bean like method, for example

```
     new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSourceYarus());
```

I did not attach any importance to this, because in all example this is true.
BUT in xml configuration caused this like "Bean" on his name, i replace call in java-config to

```
     new DataSourceTransactionManager(context.getBean("dataSourceYarus"))
```

and.... this work for me!
Because if call this method, every time creating new pool then  transaction was over